# Epsom salts to container potting mixture

Tags: soil-amendment

Is adding Epsom salt to soil based container potting mixtures, non-harmful to grow vegetables with?

Comment: Not harmful but not necessary except for some special cases like acid loving plants

Answer (score 1):

Magnesium Sulphate provides magnesium for plants that tend to need it more, such as Blueberries.

Usual applications is two tablespoons per gallon of water applied occasionally or 1 cup per 100 sq ft.

As a magnesium source it is neutral as opposed to dolomite which will raise the soil pH.

Photosynthesis depends on having magnesium available, it's one of the active parts of chlorophyll, along with assimilable iron.

Lack of magnesium is one of the causes of chlorosis, a readily identifiable condition where the veins in the leaves remain green with yellowing in the areas between. This mostly affects newer growth and slowly starves the plant of its sugar production. Lack of free assimilable iron also causes this condition in roses and other iron loving plants.